# An efficient 'drizzle' algorithm?

Tags: algorithms

What efficient implementations of a 'drizzle' algorithm are available?  The problem is, given a timestream of data in which each element is associated with a pixel in a map, how do you create that map?  Each pixel may have many data points associated with it.  Each data point may need to be weighted.

For example, in python/numpy, given a data array `d`, a weight array `w`, a map `m`, a weight map `wm`, and a mapping from d to m `xinds,yinds`, you could do:

```
for jj,(xx,yy) in enumerate(xinds,yinds):
    m[xx,yy] += (d*w)[jj]
    wm[xx,yy] += w[jj]
final_image = m/wm
```

where `xx`,`yy`,`d`, and `w` have the same length.  Also, `xx` and `yy` are matrix `x`,`y` locations.

How can this be made more efficient?  Are there tools in python or libraries in other languages to do this?  Am I even calling the algorithm by its right name?

An efficient implementation in `IDL` using the `histogram` function is shown at [David Fanning's website](http://www.idlcoyote.com/code_tips/drizzling.html)

EDIT:
After asking this question, I realized I had the answer... `numpy.bincount` does exactly what I want in numpy.  If the mapping `t = xinds + yinds*xsize` where `xsize` is the x-dimension of the map

```
# shapes of x,y indices need to be flat
x,y = (a.ravel() for a in numpy.indices(m.shape))
dc = numpy.bincount(t,d*w)
wc = numpy.bincount(t,w)
m[x,y] = dc
wm[x,y] = wc
```

([a function implementing this](http://code.google.com/p/agpy/source/browse/trunk/AG_image_tools/drizzle.py))

It would still be useful to know of other implementations of this algorithm.  Or perhaps ways to compute the `t` mapping and different weighting schemes - I don't discuss that at all above, but I think in the context in which the term was coined (Hubble imaging) there are complexities involved in determining both variables.

EDIT2: Corollary - what if I want to median-drizzle?  i.e., instead of averaging for the final map, median?

(this is not valid code, but vaguely pseudo-code... you can't have 2-dimensional lists in python, though nested lists are OK)

```
for jj,(xx,yy) in enumerate(xinds,yinds):
    m[xx,yy].append((d*w)[jj])
for jj,(xx,yy) in enumerate(xinds,yinds):
    m[xx,yy] = median(m[xx,yy])
```

Answer (score 5):

This algorithm is easy to write in a for-loop fashion and hard to express as a series of vector operations, which makes is a perfect candidate for writing it in a lower-level language (like C) and just linking it to Python (for instance with Cython). Unless there is a drizzle lib for Python, this will be both fastest and easiest solution.

Comment: Right, that's exactly the point - for loop is inefficient, so is there a C library that does this?  `numpy.bincount` is pretty good, but maybe there's better?

Comment: But this is 5 lines of C plus few for interface... If you are looking for a pure Python, I would rather seek for some [image manipulation-based](http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/image.htm) solution.